# -bash: yo: command not found I installing keystone JS on MAC OS X EL Capitan Version 10.11.3

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, bash, keystonejs

[image]

I am unable to run the command yo keystone after going through the whole installation numerous times. The $PATH is also in the screen shot posted.

Comment: Is `yo`'s directory in `PATH`?  If not then put it there.

Comment: This is what my $PATH looks like now still not working

Comment: So which directory is `yo` in?

Comment: /Users/hamadkhawaja/npm/lib/node_modules/yo

Comment: The `$PATH` in your screen-shot does not match the value in the comment 2 days ago.  I suggest you double check that this directory is in `$PATH` when you run it.  If so, then try: `Users/hamadkhawaja/npm/lib/node_modules/yo/yo keystone`.

Answer (score 0):

at first, you need to install yo tool on your machine via the following npm script:

```
$ npm install -g yo
```

then to try